# Absolute cleanest way to assign sub-methods to a method in JS?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm creating a JS library object that has a primary function, but I also want to assign sub-methods to that primary function to extend it.

So right now what I have looks like this:

```
Parser.prototype = {
    init: function(){

    },

    primaryFunction:function(){


    }
}
```

I really like this notation for assigning methods to `Parser.prototype`, but how can I use similar notation for assigning methods to `primaryFunction`? Also, the submethods are characterized by a string.  Because eventually, my goal is to be able call like this: `primaryFunction["*"]();`

It seems I can't do this:

```
primaryFunction:function(char){
    "*":function(){

    }
}
```

Sort of makes sense why, but am I forced to do this?

```
primaryFunction:function(char){
    this["*"] = function(){};
}
```

Comment: Because you can't use object syntax when you're not declaring an object? And I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish, or why. You could just declare the functions inside the function.

Comment: Right, that makes sense, now I'm asking what's the cleanest way to do this

Comment: So functions declared inside another become methods of the outer function?

Comment: No, they're scoped within the function. It sounds like you just want to embed an object inside another. Again, without really understanding the purpose it's difficult to know what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want to be able to call like: `primaryFunction["*"]()`.  Of course I could change primaryFunction to accept a parameter, but I don't want to add logic to perform certain actions based on the parameter. I'd rather just call a separate function for each possible parameter. In order to do that, then "\*" needs to be a method of primaryFunction, correct? And so simply declaring "*" to be a function inside primaryFunction wouldn't achieve that

Comment: @krb686 ... It means `primaryFunction` would need to return something addressable by string. Like an object. Like embedding an object.

Comment: Hey Dave, you can read my comments on T.J. Crowder's answer for a bit more info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a big difference between adding properties to `Parser.prototype` and adding properties to `primaryFunction`. When you add to `Parser.prototype`, you're adding properties to a non-function object that is used as the underlying prototype of any object (instance) created via the `new Parser` expression. But if you add properties to `primaryFunction`, you're adding those properties to the function object of `primaryFunction`, directly.

The result is that properties added to `Parser.prototype` become, in effect, *methods* of instances created via `new Parser`. Within calls to those "methods," provided they're made normally (`instance.init()` and similar), `this` will refer to the instance.

But properties added to `primaryFunction` are methods of the **function** `primaryFunction`, not instances created with it. If you call them in the normal way (`instance.primaryFunction["*"]()`), within the call `this` is `primaryFunction` (the function object), not `instance`.

If that's really want you want, then you simply assign them after the fact (you can't do it within the object initializer):

```
Parser.prototype.primaryFunction["*"] = function() { /* ... */ };
```

But there are relatively few use cases for doing that, not least because if you're using `Parser` as a constructor function (e.g., with `new Parser`), you probably want to do things with the instance created, and you won't have access to it in `primaryFunction["*"]` unless you do some funny stuff.

The funny stuff, FWIW, looks like this — but I'm **not** recommending it (**nor** recommending against it), just being complete:

```
/* ...inside the `Parser` function... */
this.primaryFunction["*"] = this.primaryFunction["*"].bind(this);
```

That creates a new function that, when called, will call `primaryFunction` but setting `this` to the instance created by `new Parser`, and saves the resulting function as an "own" property on the instance being created.

---

From your comment below:

> So my use case is just a parsing object that performs different
>   actions based on what characters it reads. The Parser loops through a
>   string, and my goal is to call a different function based on what the
>   current character at the index is. There will only be a set of unique
>   functions for each special character that may be in the string. For
>   instance, those characters could be: `*`, `/`, `\`, `<`, `>`,
>   essentially non alphanumerics. For anything alphanumeric, I want a
>   `default` function to handle those. So essentially, in a loop I'm
>   getting the `currentChar`, and trying to call a sub-method based on
>   which char it is. So the loop is essentially doing:
>   `this.handleChar[currentChar]()`.

The `bind` solution above would work for that. But I think I'd probably go another way: Have a private, shared map of handler functions that you call (either passing in the parser instance as an argument, or as `this`) with the characters:

```
var Parser = function() {
    var handlers = {
        "*": function(char) {
            // handle *...
        },
        "/": function(char) {
            // handle /...
        },
        // ...and so on...
        "default": function(char) {
            // default handling...
        }
    };

    function Parser() {
        // ...
    }

    // (I always advocate *augmenting*, not replacing, `FuncName.prototype` properties)

    Parser.prototype.handleChar = function() {
        var currentChar;

        while (!!(currentChar = /*...get the character...*/)) {
            (handlers[currentChar] || handlers.default).call(this, currentChar);
            // On some older JavaScript engines, you'd have to write the above like this:
            //
            //     (handlers[currentChar] || handlers["default"]).call(this, currentChar);
            //
            // ...because ES3 didn't let you use a keyword as a property name literal
            // (ES5 does, and some engines always did).
        }
    };

    return Parser;

}();
```

That example passes the parser instance as `this` by using `Function#call` (the first argument is what ends up being `this` in the function call). It also uses JavaScript's [curiously-powerful `||` operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html) to pick the function on `handlers` to call.

(If you don't care that `handlers` be private, then you don't need the wrapper.)

Comment: Sure, I see what you are saying.  So my use case is just a parsing object that performs different actions based on what characters it reads.

The Parser loops through a string, and my goal is to call a **different** function based on what the current character at the index is.  There will only be a set of unique functions for each special character that may be in the string.  For instance, those characters could be: `*, /, \, <, >`, essentially non alphanumerics.  For anything alphanumeric, I want a `default` function to handle those.  So essentially, in a loop...

Comment: I'm getting the `currentChar`, and trying to call a sub-method based on which char it is.  So the loop is essentially doing: `this.handleChar[currentChar]()`

Comment: ^^ `handleChar` is the primary function I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Additionally, as far as my real-world goal, I'm just playing with code, trying to create a parser as an experiment, maybe to later on perform certain actions, read in source code, analyze it for certain things, I don't know yet.  I know, typically one would just create a function like `handleChar(currentChar)`, and pass it in as a parameter.  The reason I really don't want to do this though is because I want to avoid embedding all the logic in that function; it  is much cleaner to read, debug, so on if I have small, separate functions that only have a few lines of code each...

Comment: @krb686: I see what you're doing. I've added to the answer.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! So just 2 quick questions then.  Typically, in the past I  have always declared at the highest level my library like `function Parser(){...`, and then added on with `Parser.prototype.doWhatever = function(){...` I am not sure where I picked that up.  I usually end up making these `node.js` libraries, but really, there would be no major difference between that and your way of assigning it to a var, correct? They just need to be exportable in node, and typically I've always done `module.exports = Parser`

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you're doing.  The outer function is just a wrapper to make things private, correct? So then what would be the difference between your way, and just moving `var handlers = {...` inside the inner `function Parser()` and removing the wrapper? Just keeping the `prototype.doWhatever` methods private as well?

Comment: @krb686: If you move `var handlers = ...` into `Parser`, they'll get recreated for every parser instance (and you'd have to store them on the instance somewhere). By defining them *outside* `Parser`, all instances can share the same set of handler functions. *"Just keeping the `prototype.doWhatever` methods private as well?"* No, they aren't private, they're accessible as properties on the instances.